# Dividir en consulta Nosql

Tags: json, mongodb

Quiero hacer una consulta que me proporcione para cada libro, cual es su proporción entre número de páginas y precio. Mi consulta está a medias y seria así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de un documento libro es así:

```
{
  _id:valor,
  tema:"Libros",
  nombre:valor,
  precio:valor,
  paginas:valor
}
```

El problema es que no se como dividir el número de páginas entre su precio en Nosql ¿Que tendría que ir en `Proporcion:` ?

Comment: COnsejo: todo el código se comparte como texto, no como imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se necesita realizar una operación aritmética (división) entre 2 valores de un documento en una colección en [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).

El modelo del documento almacenado en la colección es la siguiente:

```js
{
  _id:valor,
  tema: String,
  nombre: String, // asumo un tipo String
  precio: Number, // asumo un tipo Number
  paginas: Number // asumo un tipo Number
}
```

Se desea obtener un documento que contenga los siguiente elementos:

```js
{
  _id: String, // Nombre del libro
  proporción: Number // resultado de dividir paginas entre precio
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la operación necesitas usar el [operador aritmético](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-expression-operators) llamado [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/#exp._S_divide) del proceso de [Agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) de MongoDB.

Este operador recibe 2 valores o argumentos y realiza la operación de división:

```
arg1 / arg2
```

Ambos valores pueden ser cualquier tipo de [*expresión*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions), siempre y cuando ambos resuelvan a un tipo `Number`.

La etapa `$group` que realizas no es necesaria, a menos que tengas varios documentos con el mismo campo `nombre` (es lo haces en tu código).

Los nombres de los campos debes mantenerlos coherentes, en tu imagen se ve que usas: `Tema`, pero en tu modelo de documento tienes: `tema`, lo mismo para `Nombre`.

Por ejemplo, podrías hacer el cálculo que te interesa de la siguiente forma:

```js
db.aficiones.aggregate([
  { $match: { tema: 'Libros'} },
  { $project: { _id: '$nombre', proporcion: {$divide: ['$paginas', '$precio']}} }
]);
```

Suponiendo que tu colección aficiones tiene los siguientes documentos:

```js
> db.aficiones.find({ tema: 'Libros'});
[
  {_id: 5ece66be19ff556374d71f59, tema: 'Libros', nombre: 'Javascript for Dummies', precio: 30.5, paginas: 340, __v: 0},
  {_id: 5ece66be19ff556374d71f5a, tema: 'Libros', nombre: 'Java for Dummies', precio: 35, paginas: 240, __v: 0},
  {_id: 5ece66be19ff556374d71f5b, tema: 'Libros', nombre: 'C# for Dummies', precio: 25, paginas: 440, __v: 0},
  {_id: 5ece66be19ff556374d71f5c, tema: 'Libros', nombre: 'C++ for Dummies', precio: 48.5, paginas: 620, __v: 0},
  {_id: 5ece66be19ff556374d71f5d, tema: 'Libros', nombre: 'Python for Dummies', precio: 32, paginas: 290, __v: 0},
  {_id: 5ece66be19ff556374d71f5e, tema: 'Libros', nombre: 'C for Dummies', precio: 29, paginas: 478, __v: 0},
  {_id: 5ece66be19ff556374d71f5f, tema: 'Libros', nombre: 'PHP for Dummies', precio: 31, paginas: 195, __v: 0}
]
```

Aplicando la agregación propuesta, el resultado será similar al siguiente:

```js
> let aggregate = [
  {$match: {tema: 'Libros'}},
  {$project: {_id: '$nombre', proporcion: {$divide: ['$paginas', '$precio']}}}
];

> db.aficiones.aggregate(aggregate);

[
  { _id: 'Javascript for Dummies', proporcion: 11.147540983606557 },
  { _id: 'Java for Dummies', proporcion: 6.857142857142857 },
  { _id: 'C# for Dummies', proporcion: 17.6 },
  { _id: 'C++ for Dummies', proporcion: 12.783505154639176 },
  { _id: 'Python for Dummies', proporcion: 9.0625 },
  { _id: 'C for Dummies', proporcion: 16.482758620689655 },
  { _id: 'PHP for Dummies', proporcion: 6.290322580645161 }
]
```

De esta forma obtienes el resultado esperado.